# Error : org.codehaus.groovy.control.CompilationUnit.(Lorg/codehaus/groovy/control/CompilerConfiguration;Ljava/security/

Tags: apache, maven, groovy

I am encountering this exception:

```
org.codehaus.groovy.control.CompilationUnit.(Lorg/codehaus/groovy/control/CompilerConfiguration;Ljava/security/CodeSource;Lgroovy/lang/GroovyClassLoader;Lgroovy/lang/GroovyClassLoader;ZLjava/lang/String;)V"
```

Here is what `pom.xml` file looks like:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>com.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>spock</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>

    <name>spock</name>
    <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>

    <build>
        <pluginManagement>
            <plugins>
                <!-- Required plugin -->
                <plugin>
                    <!-- The gmavenplus plugin is used to compile Groovy code -->
                    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.codehaus.gmaven/gmaven-plugin -->
                    <groupId>org.codehaus.gmaven</groupId>
                    <artifactId>gmaven-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>1.4</version>
                </plugin>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.codehaus.gmavenplus</groupId>
                    <artifactId>gmavenplus-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>1.6.1</version>
                    <executions>
                        <execution>
                            <goals>
                                <goal>compile</goal>
                                <goal>testCompile</goal>
                            </goals>
                        </execution>
                    </executions>
                </plugin>
                <!-- Optional plugin -->
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                    <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>2.21.0</version>
                    <configuration>
                        <useFile>false</useFile>
                        <includes>
                            <include>**/*Spec.groovy</include>
                        </includes>
                    </configuration>
                </plugin>
            </plugins>
        </pluginManagement>
    </build>

    <dependencies>
        <!-- Required dependency for using Spock -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.spockframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spock-core</artifactId>
            <version>1.1-groovy-2.4</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <!-- Optional dependencies for using Spock -->
        <dependency> <!-- Specify explicitly the Groovy version that matches the spock version -->
            <groupId>org.codehaus.groovy</groupId>
            <artifactId>groovy-all</artifactId>
            <version>2.4.15</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- Enables mocking of classes (in addition to interfaces) -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.groovy</groupId>
            <artifactId>groovy</artifactId>
            <version>2.4.5</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>cglib</groupId>
            <artifactId>cglib-nodep</artifactId>
            <version>3.2.6</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <!-- Enables mocking of classes without default constructor (together with
            CGLIB) -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.objenesis</groupId>
            <artifactId>objenesis</artifactId>
            <version>2.6</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</project>
```

Comment: Can you share more context?

Comment: Provide the complete exception stack trace.

Comment: I want to get started with SPOCK framework, creation of groovy class file is giving this error.
Followed the steps mentioned in
https://www.pluralsight.com/guides/introduction-to-testing-with-bdd-and-the-spock-framework
along with the POM.xml
After adding the POM.xml file to my maven project replaced all the older dependency versions with latest versions and downloaded Groovy plugin from eclipse market place
In File->New->Other i am able to see Groovy folder under that when i select the Groovy class it is throwing error

Comment: An error has occurred. See error log for more details.
org.codehaus.groovy.control.CompilationUnit.<init>(Lorg/codehaus/groovy/control/CompilerConfiguration;Ljava/security/CodeSource;Lgroovy/lang/GroovyClassLoader;Lgroovy/lang/GroovyClassLoader;ZLjava/lang/String;)V

Comment: Hi, Can anyone help me on this. Issue still persists